# Javascript store html/jquery in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the following code in a variable rendered as html and not as a string:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
    <center>
        <h1>TO THE TIME</h1>
        <script type="application/javascript">
           var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({
                                //year      : 2015,
                                month   : 11,    
                                day     : 11,     
                                hour    : 00,    
                                ampm    : "am",  
                                minute  : 00,         
                                second  : 00,       
                                width:290, 
                                height:60,  
                                rangeHi:"month",
                                rangeLo:"seconds",
                                style:"flip"
                            });

        </script>
    </center>
</div>
```

I tried storing it as

```
htmlcontent[idgrab] = '<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">'+
'<center>'+
'<h1>TO THE TIME</h1>'+
'<script type="application/javascript">'+
'var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({'+
                                'month  : 11,'+    
                                'day    : 11,'+     
                                'hour   : 00,'+    
                                'ampm   : "am",'+    
                                'minute : 00,'+         
                                'second : 00,'+       
                                'width:290,'+ 
                                'height:60,'+  
                                'rangeHi:"month",'+
                                'rangeLo:"seconds",'+
                                'style:"flip"'+
                                '});'+

'</script>'+
'</center>'+
'</div>';
```

But that didn't work, basically I have code that pulls dynamically created html which I managed to grab using `.`html however this one I've only managed to show up as either a string using `""`; or break the site entirely.

Edit:

The normal renderer pulls code with this:

```
htmlcontent[idgrab] = $('#'+idgrab).html();
```

which works fine for basic html that does not include javascript but for this div in particular, it seems to need to be manually slotted into the array which im having trouble with because the div needs to be stored WITHOUT executing the javascript code (it needs to be executed after the array is invoked).

Comment: *"I have code that pulls dynamically created html"*, which code? How are you rendering your html. Chances are the issue is there (it's probably escaping < to &lt; and so on).

Comment: I recommend making it clear what libraries you're using. It appears that you're using the countdown timer from this website.

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `$.parseHTML`

```js
var htmlcontent = {};

htmlcontent["idgrab"] = '<div style=display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle>'
+ '<center>'
+ '<h1>TO THE TIME</h1>'
+ '<script type="application/javascript">'
+ 'var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({'
+ 'month'+  ':'+ '11,'
+ 'day'+ ':'+ '11,'
+ 'hour'+   ':'+ '00,'
+ 'ampm' +  ':' + '"am",'
+ 'minute' +':'+ '00,'
+ 'second' + ':' + '00,'
+ 'width' +':' + '290,'
+ 'height' +':' + '60,'
+ 'rangeHi' + ':'+ '"month",'
+ 'rangeLo' +':' + '"seconds",'
+ 'style' +':' + '"flip"'
+ '});'
+ '</scr'+'ipt>'
+ '</center>'
+ '</div>';

var html = $.parseHTML(htmlcontent["idgrab"], document, true);
console.log(htmlcontent["idgrab"], html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I mean yours worked but when the div is rendered, it literally replaces the page with just the timer, same with the other proposed solutions (except I couldn't get parsehtml to work).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to parse html string into a DOM element (tree) without jquery you an do [this](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#parse_html)

```
var parseHTML = function(str) {
  var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
  tmp.body.innerHTML = str;
  return tmp.body.children;
};

parseHTML(htmlString);
```

Or simply use `$.parseHTML(htmlString);` if you have jquery in your site

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/gp5Leg2v/)

Comment: I have tried to use parseHTML however it shows up as it doesn't exist I am running a cloud version of jquery from here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Comment: @GinzoMilani I've added working fiddle to the answer using your jquery link

Answer (score 0):

Normally you want to keep JavaScript out of the HTML entirely and just bind to the relevant DOM events, e.g. `$(document).ready(function(){})` or `$(window).load(function(){})`. Most UI frameworks let you hook into several events, including when the element is first rendered to the DOM.

If you need to output HTML for use in dynamic widgets, you can try escaping them before rendering them in the DOM, e.g. `htmlspecialchars` for PHP or [escape-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escape-html)'s `escape` method for Node.js. If you took that route, best practice is probably to put that into a [data-* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) like [jQuery Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/tmpl.php) would have you do.

Comment: It absolutely must contain javascript just because I need the javascripts function to execute at a certain location as it will create a timer wherever it is executed

Comment: So you need to control the context of the execution, which can be done using `<function-name>.apply`?

Comment: @GinzoMilani Click the blue square to see it.

Comment: @GinzoMilani ... and also definitive proof that you don't need the JS to be at exactly that location in the HTML.

Comment: I used yours mixed with guest271314s reply but the timer literally replaces the whole page

Comment: You need to use `function(){<your-code>}.apply(<selected-element>);` to make sure `this` refers to the actual DOM element. <selected-element> can be something like `$('#my-element-id')[0]`.

Comment: You may also be able to use `$('#my-element-id').load(function(){<your-code>})`. That should still have the intended effect.